# Oracle Query Result of records for particular status and description

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a Oracle table as shown below:

```
Orders
---------
OrderFullFillID
Description
OrderDate
OrderStatus
Qty

Below are sample records

1    PTS123   1/1/2012     Settled     10
2    PTS123   1/1/2012    ArchSettled  10
3    PTS124   2/1/2012    Settled      10
4    PTS124   2/1/2012    Settled      20
5    PTS125   2/1/2012    Settled      20
6    PTS125   2/1/2012    Settled      20
7    PTS126   2/1/2012    Settled      20
8    PTS126   2/1/2012    ArchSettled  20
```

How do I display records with same Description and duplicate status='settled'?
There will be two records with same description, statusdate but different status. 
I need to list only the ones with status='Settled' and description is same.

In the above sample the query should return the following:

```
    3    PTS124   2/1/2012    Settled      10
    4    PTS124   2/1/2012    Settled      20
    5    PTS125   2/1/2012    Settled      20
    6    PTS125   2/1/2012    Settled      20
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT OrderFulFillID,
       Description,
       OrderData,
       OrderStatus,
       Qty
  FROM orders a
 WHERE status = 'Settled'
   AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM orders b
                    WHERE a.description = b.description
                      AND a.statusDate  = b.statusDate
                      AND a.status     != b.status )
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderFulFillID,
       Description,
       OrderData,
       OrderStatus,
       Qty
  FROM orders a
  WHERE status = 'Settled'
    AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                  FROM orders b
                  WHERE a.description     = b.description
                    AND a.OrderFulFillID != b.OrderFulFillID
                    AND a.status          = b.status )
```